# Swift 3 - do-catch and throw

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift3

When working with a function that `throws`, we use a `do-catch` to handle possible errors. Let's say we are writing a function and we want the function to propagate the error:

```
public func myFunc() throws
{
    do
    {
        let obj = try convert(param: 42)
        // work with obj...
    }
    catch
    {
        print("failed: \(String(describing: error))")
        throw MyError.ConversionFailed
    }
}
```

That's great. But, let's say now we have custom logic in `myFunc` that might cause the function to throw a different type of error:

```
public func myFunc() throws
{
    do
    {
        let obj = try convert(param: 42)
        // work with obj...
        if obj is Array
        {
            // great, continue working with obj...
        }
        else 
        {
            throw MyError.NotAnArray
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("failed: \(String(describing: error))")
        throw MyError.ConversionFailed
    }
}
```

But this wouldn't work: the inner `throw` will be caught by `do-catch` and `myFunc` will just throw the error `ConversionFailed`, instead of the `NotAnArray` error.

One way to make this to work is:

```
public func myFunc() throws
{
    do
    {
        let obj = try convert(param: 42)
        // work with obj...
        if obj is Array
        {
            // great, continue working with obj...
        }
        else 
        {
            throw MyError.NotAnArray(object: obj)
        }
    }
    catch MyError.NotAnArray(let obj)
    {
        throw MyError.NotAnArray(object: obj)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("failed: \(String(describing: error))")
        throw MyError.ConversionFailed
    }
}
```

That works, but it seems repetitive, especially when there are associated values, and I might need several `catch`es if the custom logic is complex. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substitute the error thrown by `convert()`
by another error then call `convert()` in a local do/catch context.
The outer do/catch is not needed because
a throwing function "automatically" propagates errors up
to the caller (compare [How to pass an Error up the stack trace in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751609/how-to-pass-an-error-up-the-stack-trace-in-swift)).

```
public func myFunc() throws
{
    let obj: Any // or whatever type convert() returns
    do {
        obj = try convert(param: 42)
    } catch {
        throw MyError.ConversionFailed
    }
    // work with obj...
    if obj is Array {
        // great, continue working with obj...
    } else {
        throw MyError.NotAnArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, you are right. Automatic propagation is also a good point, I didn't know that. But what if I change my intension to throw a custom error instead of rethrowing the same one?

Comment: @Stephenye: You mean substituting the error thrown by `aFunctionThatThrows()` by a custom error? In that case you have to call the function in a local do/catch context.

Comment: yes, I updated the question to better illustrate what I meant. And I guess I need another catch in that case right?

Comment: @Stephenye: See updated answer, hopefully that is what you are looking for.