# Does return need to be called after an escaping completion block?

Tags: ios, swift

If I have the following code:

```
func getData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    // Do stuff
    completion()
    print(hello)
}
```

When the completion block is called, will the function automatically return, or will it continue running and "hello" be printed?

Comment: you do not need to use return. Execution will continue and it will print the value of hello

Comment: @Scriptable actually I'm trying to stop the running of the function when completion is called, so I guess that means I do need to use return after `completion()` then

Comment: just dont put any code afterwards. or if you really need to you put return in there which will stop execution

Comment: @Scriptable ok thanks

Comment: Yes it will continue running. You can consider it as delegate or block in objc where execution continues after calling delegate / block

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: See [How to exit a function scope from inner function using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47251358)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Completion handlers are just like any other ordinary closure. In some cases people might want to run some more code after `completion`, so that's why they designed them like so. When you call them, they run. And after they return, the code below runs. They cannot replace a `return` statement. If you want to stop running the rest of the method after the `completion()` bit, put a `return` there.

**Unless**, your completion handler is declared to return `Never`, in which case it will either terminate your whole app, or run indefinitely. In that case any code after it won't be run. :)

Comment: This is such a simple thing but sometimes even after coding for so many years many people don't know about this.