# Swift return or throw

Tags: swift, exception

The following pattern is quite common in certain places in my code, but it doesn't feel Swifty:

```
if let res = calcSomething() {
    return res
} else {
    throw err.invalidSomething
}
```

In English: return the calue of `calcSomething()` if it returned a non-nil, throw an exception otherwise.

I was hoping for a structure that looks like the following:

```
return calcSomething() ?? throw err.invalidSomething
```

But so far didn't find anything similar. Am I missing something?

Comment: if your calcSomething method throws: `return try calcSomething()`

Comment: An “error-throwing nil-coalescing operator” (and possible implementations) was suggested on swift-evolution: https://forums.swift.org/t/pre-draft-nil-coalescing-and-errors/2070

Comment: In addition to @LeoDabus point about being `calcSomething` function throwable, you could check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751609/how-to-pass-an-error-up-the-stack-trace-in-swift

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. And by that submission I understand that the most concise version is Malik's answer.

Comment: @LeoDabus it doesn't throw; it might do something like extracting a value from a dictionary (returning nil if not found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `null coalesce` in a return statement. However, you can do something like this

```
guard let res = calcSomething() else { throw err.invalidSomething }
return res
```

Comment: Your second line should probably be `return res`. Fixed.

Comment: @noamtm Yeah. Sorry. My bad

Answer (score 1):

For such a case, I would prefer to use the `guard` statement instead, so it would be similar to:

```
func myFunction() throws {
    guard let res = calcSomething() else {
        throw err.invalidSomething
    }

    // keep going now...

    // if something went wrong, you might want to throw another error:
    throw err.invalidSomething

    // if everything is ok:
    return res
}
```

The `guard` would bounce the calling of the function, by throwing the desired error directly if `calcSomething()` is `nil`.

---

About `return calcSomething() ?? throw err.invalidSomething`:

It seems to be an obvious goal when implementing such a function, however as some point it is not so logical to the language because the [nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) (`??`):

> The nil-coalescing operator (a ?? b) **unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is `nil`**. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.
>
> The nil-coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> > `a != nil ? a! : b`

which means that it `returns` a value as a result; `throw err.invalidSomething` does *not* a value to be returned, instead it is an exceptional case for something went wrong that throws an error.

Comment: Your "if everything is ok" should probably return `res`, not calculate it again.

Comment: @noamtm based on your code snippet `return calcSomething() ?? throw err.invalidSomething` is seems that you are aiming to return `calcSomething()`, up to you :)

Comment: Yes, I want to return the value of `calcSomething()`; but it's already stored in `res`!